# mariadb fonction, procedure error You have an error in your SQL

Tags: function, mariadb, procedure

```
DELIMITER /
CREATE FUNCTION filltimeDim ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE vQuarter VARCHAR(6);
    DECLARE vMonth_Name VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE vdate_id date;
    DECLARE vyear_id CHAR(4);
    DECLARE vweekly_Name VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE vMonth_Num TINYINT(10);
    DECLARE vweekday_Num TINYINT(10);
    BEGIN
        SET vdate_id =  CONVERT('1998-01-01', DATE);
        WHILE (CONVERT('vdate_id' USING utf8) <=  '2002-12-31')
        LOOP
            SET vyear_id =  YEAR(vdate_id);
            SET vQuarter =  QUARTER(vdate_id);
            SET vMonth_Name =  MONTHNAME(vdate_id);
            SET vweekly_Name =  DAYOFWEEK(vdate_id);
            SET vMonth_Num =  MONTH(vdate_id);
            SET vweekday_Num =  WEEKDAY(vdate_id);
            INSERT INTO Time_Dim VALUES 
            (vdate_id, vyear_id, vquarter, vMonth_Name,vweekly_Name,vMonth_Num,vweekday_Num);
            SET vdate_id = vdate_id + 1;
        END LOOP;   
    END;
END; /
```

Error: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
    DECLARE vQuarter VARCHAR(6);
    DECLARE vMonth_Name VARCHAR(20);
    ' at line 2

Comment: You are explicitly declaring a function. It's expecting the RETURN declaration before the BEGIN. Take a look at the documentation: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-function/

Comment: Do you really need the `CONVERTs`?  The datatype DATE and the strings you have should be compatible.

Comment: And `SET vdate_id = vdate_id + 1;` won't work with a `DATE`.  Instead do `SET vdate_id = vdate_id + INTERVAL 1 DAY;`

Comment: A "time_dim" dimension table is usually a bad idea for Data Warehousing, at least when you _start_ with the dim table to do a lookup (such as find all "monday" rows).

Comment: Consider using a "sequence table"; this can avoid the cursor, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to create a [stored procedure](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/stored-procedure-overview/) instead of a function.

Also, MariaDB uses the `DO` keyword instead of `LOOP` to mark the start and end of the [`WHILE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/while/) loop. Here's a fixed version of the SQL that completes successfully:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE filltimeDim ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE vQuarter VARCHAR(6);
    DECLARE vMonth_Name VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE vdate_id date;
    DECLARE vyear_id CHAR(4);
    DECLARE vweekly_Name VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE vMonth_Num TINYINT(10);
    DECLARE vweekday_Num TINYINT(10);
    BEGIN
        SET vdate_id =  CONVERT('1998-01-01', DATE);
        WHILE (CONVERT(vdate_id USING utf8) <=  '2002-12-31')
        DO
            SET vyear_id =  YEAR(vdate_id);
            SET vQuarter =  QUARTER(vdate_id);
            SET vMonth_Name =  MONTHNAME(vdate_id);
            SET vweekly_Name =  DAYOFWEEK(vdate_id);
            SET vMonth_Num =  MONTH(vdate_id);
            SET vweekday_Num =  WEEKDAY(vdate_id);
            INSERT INTO Time_Dim VALUES
            (vdate_id, vyear_id, vquarter, vMonth_Name,vweekly_Name,vMonth_Num,vweekday_Num);
            SET vdate_id = vdate_id + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
        END WHILE;
    END;
END; //
```

Note that the modified SQL uses date arithmetic instead of numeric arithmetic. This correctly updates the date whereas the original caused a date overflow.

Comment: Thanks! Oops! I came late.
Anyway, after spending some time on MariaDB documentation, I managed to do it and made it work, and yes I needed a procedure.
I didn't quite understand date arithmetic and numeric arithmetic?

Comment: If you are using dates as the data type, you must increment them with `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY`, otherwise you'll get errors.